# How do I customize the helper using draggable in jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a custom element with text taken from the element "being dragged" using a helper function. My problem is that ui is undefined, so I don't know how to get a hold of the source of the drag.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: function(event, ui) {
        var foo = $('<span style="white-space:nowrap;">DRAG TEST</span>'); 
        return foo;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `helper` function you're applying [is invoked the following way](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L244):

```
 $(o.helper.apply(this.element[0], [event]))
```

That means that `this` refers to the `.draggable` you want inside that function, for example:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: function(event) {
    return $('<span style="white-space:nowrap;"/>')
            .text($(this).text() + " helper");
  }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HU33J/).

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Maybe just remove the event and ui in the function calls, or are they used in some way?

Comment: @Cros - `event` is there, but yes `ui` is extraneous, always `undefined`, I'll remove it in the answer.

Comment: @NickCraver Hi Nick, your answer works great.  I'm trying to return the original element (but shrunk down).  returning $(this).clone() works fine, but returning just $(this) doesn't move the element, I wondered if you might know why?

Comment: @CrimsonChin - not sure I'm following 100%, can you link me to an example?

Comment: @NickCraver sorry I attached the wrong fiddle a minute ago.  This one should show what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks for your time and knowledge! http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/A3fN8/5/